# Why does the output of a transformer increase when connected to a battery for charging?

Tags: ac, transformer, dc

I have a 110VAC- 14VAC 5A transformer with me. I have the output rectified and it shows like 13.8VDC. But when I connect it to my 12V SLA for charging it output rises to 15.8V instantly and I hear a lot of fizzing from the battery. WHy does this happen?

Comment: What's the measured voltage across the battery, off load and off the charger?

Comment: @TonyM I think it was around 12.42Volts off charger before I connected it to the transformer.

Comment: Oh, OK...that's my next theory scrapped, then :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are measuring full wave rectified DC with a meter, and see 13.8v average (average is what a DC meter reads), then the peak will be rather larger, on the order of 20v. This is what is causing an excessive current to flow into the battery. As the battery is fissing, its terminal voltage rises above what's safe, to give you the 15.8v you read on the meter.

Comment: Thanks. Okay so is there anyway I can reduce it to 14V -13.8V without much current loss?